# Как в Delphi передать указатель вместо нетипизированной переменной?

Tags: delphi, типы, buffer

Как выполнить преобразование типа, чтобы передать указатель вместо нетипизированной переменной, т.е. передать указатель вместо Var? Сейчас я вынужден переписать прототип функции ReadFile, чтобы использовать TMemoryStream в качестве буфера.

```
function ReadFile(hFile: THandle; **lpBuffer: Pointer**; nNumberOfBytesToRead: DWORD;
  var lpNumberOfBytesRead: DWORD; lpOverlapped: POverlapped): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'ReadFile';
...
//
  procedure PipeToSringList( hPipe: THANDLE; SL: TStringList );
  var
    dwNumberOfBytesRead: Cardinal;
    MS: TMemoryStream;
  begin
    SL.Text := '';
    MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      MS.Size := GetFileSize( hPipe, nil );
      if MS.Size = 0 then
        Exit;
      ReadFile( hPipe, **MS.Memory**, MS.Size, dwNumberOfBytesRead, nil );
      MS.Size := dwNumberOfBytesRead;
      SL.LoadFromStream( MS );
    finally MS.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Параметр `Buffer` в дельфийском описании ReadFile объявлен как [нетипизированный var-параметр](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Untyped_Parameters).

Это значит, что в качестве этого параметра нельзя передавать значение, а только переменную. Причём адрес компилятор вычислит сам. В данном случае `Memory` - уже указатель, адрес в  памяти, так что придётся разыменовать его, например, так:

```
ReadFile( hPipe, PChar(MS.Memory)^,...
```

Подобный же механизм используется, если нужно, например, читать из стрима в строку или динамический массив (или писать)

```
MemStream.Read(PChar(strng)^, Length(strng)*SizeOf(Char))

// не переменная динамического массива, а первый элемент его тела!
FilStream.Write(Bytes[0], num)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, оказалось достаточно MS.Memory^.